# entire image does not show up in title-section of web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image, which I am trying to see in the title section of the web page. However, only part of the image shows up, I would like to see the entire image.

This is the code to show up the image

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="background: url('image1.jpg'); color: white;">
            <center>
                <h1>Sonic Train</h1>
            </center>
            <center>Train machine learning models at Sonic speed...</center>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It can seen in action [here](http://aftab1.cloudapp.net/SonicTrain/)

The entire image looks as follows, however, only part of the image is seen.

[image]

Comment: The image is the background of the `div`, and the height of the div is smaller than that of the image. I'm not sure what else you're expecting to happen?

Comment: you can have a look at [scaling background images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Scaling_background_images), but this will not adjust the height of your `div`

Answer (score 1):

You could use css `height` property to increase div height, like @Rory McCrossan mentioned in comment *the div is smaller than that of the image*, e.g :

```
<div class="col-sm-12" style="background:url('image1.jpg');color:white; height: 500px;">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: or using min-height: 500px;